# Twitter Bootstrap: How do I get the selected value of dropdown?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need to get the value a user selects from a twitter bootstrap dropdown. Once the user selects a value I want the dropdown to display that value. So, the user selects 'pending' then I want to change the selected dropdown value from that and, when the user completes the form, I want to retrieve the selected value. Would someone be able to point me in the right direction?

```
<div class="btn-group">
  <i class="dropdown-arrow dropdown-arrow-inverse"></i>
  <button class="btn btn-primary">status</button>
  <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-inverse">
    <li><a href="#fakelink">pending</a></li>
    <li><a href="#fakelink">active</a></li>
    <li><a href="#fakelink">discontinued</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Is the answer below what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes. The two answers combined are pretty much what I need. I may need to ask a follow up about how to set one of the lis as active...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Bootstrap provides you with minimum required functionality for your implementation, they aren't dropdowns instead they are mere ul, li's with css applied on it and some events registered in the bootstrap plugin for toggling the button to display them as dropdown.  This one you need to do on your own.

Set up some identifier to the status button say a className `btnStatus` and bind a click event to the dropdown links. and do something like this?

```
$('.dropdown-inverse li > a').click(function(e){
    $('.btnStatus').text(this.innerHTML);
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/P9fpd/)**

Answer (score 14):

I had the same issue.  The solution is pretty easy and I think the answers above may be overcomplicating a bit.

Just use $(this).text()

Assign a class name to the "" bit then..

```
$(".yourUlClassName li a").click( function() {
    var yourText = $(this).text();
});
```

Comment: This will not work on touch devices, cause they become an `.dropdown-backdrop` overlay which catches all click events and prevent further execution with `return false`.

Answer (score 2):

you can try this:

u can use class or id for selector to select easier the element.
for use the value also u can use the `value` in u javascript with jQuery.

```
    $().ready(function(){
        $('a').click(function(){
            var value = $(this).text();
            alert(value);
        });
    });
```

**Demo**:  http://jsfiddle.net/mr_mohsen_rasouli/A8m39/

Answer (score 0):

Try like this -

```
$(document.body).on('click', '.dropdown-menu li a', function (e) {
    alert($(this).text());
});
```

Demo - [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t0mt7joe/)