# How to select value of dropdown using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

I have a dropdown using boostrap. I need to store the value they select from the dropdown in a variable, but for now I'm just trying to print it.

```
window.alert($("#list_userInput_location option:selected").val());
```

It displays 'undefined'. If I do this:

```
window.alert($("#list_userInput_location option:selected").text());
```

It displays an empty string.
Also tried this:

```
window.alert($("#list_userInput_location").val());
```

Displays 'undefined' again.

So confused..........
Any thoughts?

EDIT:
Here's a fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/QMsQU/11/

Comment: My guess is the nothing is selected? Or the ID is incorrect? you have the correct syntax.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ttggepyu/

Comment: The third one should be fine for a `<select>` element. Please show us the code that creates the select element.

Comment: more code please. a fiddle would be helpful as well. what you have is vague.

Comment: Maybe here have what you need: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19736008/twitter-bootstrap-how-do-i-get-the-selected-value-of-dropdown

Comment: @bytecode77 Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/QMsQU/11/

Comment: I updated my answer and your jsFiddle. See.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In response to your jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/QMsQU/12/

```
$("#list_userInput_location").val()
```

is the correct CSS selector and `.val()` returns the content of `value="..."`. not the text inside the `<option>` tag.

This however requires that your `<select>` element has an ID of "list_userInput_location", i.e.

```
<select id="list_userInput_location">
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need the # in front of the name. Perhaps you could instead use something like this?

```
$( "select.list_userInput_location" ).val();
```

Im not 100% sure "select." is needed.

Comment: This requires element to have a **class** of `list_userInput_location`, not an ID.

Comment: @bytecode77 Adding an id to the select field could be an easy solution?

Comment: The OP probably uses an ID and your answer addresses the class, so it's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

something like this should do:

```
$('#list_userInput_location').on('change', function(){
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

This will give you the value each time an option is selected.

[**Here's an example**](https://jsfiddle.net/rqw8ec5L/1/)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you can use Jquery. The reason is am providing a Jquery example is because you used Jquery in the tags.

I used:

```
$('some select ID').find(':selected').val()
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/swollavg/pwo9x33k/) is a fiddle